Why is gmail showing multiple email aliases to recipients?
I've just set up a new business email through gmail at a custom domain. The primary account name is firstlast@customdomain.com.
I added two aliases: first@customdomain.com and editor@customdomain.com.
The problem is that I'm finding that sending an email from one of these aliases causes the recipient to see the other aliases alongside it, as seen here:

When they hover the sender email address, instead of only seeing what it was sent from, they see the other alias as well, despite it having not been used. And sometimes they see the parent email address instead, firstlast@customdomain.com.
How can I control this so that they only see the email that was used to send it? Do I need to stop using aliases and instead create entirely separate accounts that are delegated to the parent account?

To address this issue with Gmail aliases, you have a few options:

Separate accounts:
Creating separate accounts for each email address is the most reliable way to ensure recipients only see the specific address used to send the email. You can then use Gmail's account delegation feature to manage these accounts from a single interface.

Configure "Send mail as":
Instead of using aliases, set up each address as a separate "Send mail as" identity:



Go to Gmail Settings > Accounts and Import
In the "Send mail as" section, add your other addresses
When composing an email, select the desired address from the "From" dropdown


Check SMTP settings:
Ensure each "Send mail as" identity is configured with the correct SMTP settings for your custom domain.

Review Google Workspace settings:
If you're using Google Workspace, check the admin console for any settings that might be affecting how email addresses are displayed.

Test with different email clients:
Send test emails to accounts using various email clients to see if the issue is specific to certain recipients or universal.


If these steps don't resolve the issue, creating separate accounts may be the best solution.
